# How to configure apache server with localhost virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I am new to Apache.

I am editing the httpd.config to point virtual host to a specific filesystem location.

Here is what I am trying:

```
127.0.0.1

DocumentRoot "/Users/MyUser/Documents/StoreFront"

Alias StoreFront /Users/MyUser/Documents/StoreFront

<Directory /Users/MyUser/Documents/StoreFront>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

I cannot restart the server after making these changes. I get the following errors:

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 82: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
Syntax error on line 161 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
Invalid command '127.0.0.1', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
httpd not running, trying to start
```

Can someone help me out?

**Update**

I have the following now:

This is what my hosts file looks like:

```
    # Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

This is the virtualhost I have in my httpd.config:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Nick/Documents/StoreFront"
    ServerName localhost
  <Directory "/Users/Nick/Documents/StoreFront">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After making these changes I am trying to restart the server with following:

> apachectl -k restart

Error:

> /usr/sbin/apachectl: line 82: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
>   httpd not running, trying to start
>   (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>   (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   Unable to open logs

Comment: Well, are you root?

Comment: Ahh.. you think the process does not have permissions to run perhaps?

Comment: 9 years, 8k views, and not one upvote?  hey! here's 1.

Answer (score 3):

> (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs

You are not root.

You must be root to start or stop apache.

Comment: Seems likely adaptr has it here.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `ServerName 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks.. but I got the same error.  Tried: localhost 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Nick: Neither `127.0.0.1` nor `localhost 127.0.0.1` are valid commands in the configuration. The `ServerName` part is supposed to stay that way (i.e. *that* is the command name).

Comment: No, **really** `ServerName`, the characters "S", then "e" and so on. You are trying to say "The ServerName is 127.0.0.1" not "localhost is 120.0.0.1".

Answer (score 0):

An IP isn't the server name.

This is what i use in my local setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/dan/htdocs/mysite.net/www"
    ServerName mysite.local
  <Directory "/Users/dan/htdocs/mysite.net">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in my hosts file i have this line:

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.local
```

My setup above is for OS X, but i also have the same exact setup other then file paths for a windows xp machine.

Comment: What do you mean by hosts file? Not the httpd.config?

Comment: I am also running os x btw

Comment: /etc/hosts  file.  It like a local DNS

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to figure the virtualhost to serve only to localhost (i.e you can visit it by going to 127.0.0.1 from the same box, but not from any external ip) use the following config line.

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to start Apache httpd.exe (I am using x64 VC11 example here)

```
http://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC11/
```

Be sure that you have installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 : VC11 vcredist_x64/86.exe

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
```

You may need to have Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 (VS2012.3)

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 (vcredirect.exe)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835600
```

Unzip httpd-2.4.4-win64-VC11.zip and copy paste in

```
C:\Apache24
```

Unzip modules-2.4-win64-VC11.zip and copy paste them in

```
C:\Apache24\modules

http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=25091
```

For further info on the modules see the Apache Lounge VC10 Win64 download page and/or the readme in the .zip's there.

```
http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/
```

In

```
C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf
```

un-comment (remove # sign) starting below this like copy pasted list in here

```
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so

LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
LoadModule data_module modules/mod_data.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule heartmonitor_module modules/mod_heartmonitor.so
LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reflector_module modules/mod_reflector.so
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
LoadModule session_crypto_module modules/mod_session_crypto.so
LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule slotmem_plain_module modules/mod_slotmem_plain.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so
```

Then find

```
C:\Apache24\bin\ApacheMonitor.exe
```

and double click on it.

Then in Command Prompt (CMD.exe) type

```
C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe
```

and press enter. It shows any error remaining.

Build with the latest Update 3 Visual Studio® 2012 aka VC11. VC11 has improvements, fixes and optimizations over VC10 in areas like Performance, MemoryManagement and Stability. For example code quality tuning and improvements done across different code generation areas for "speed". And makes more use of modern processors and win7, win8, 2008 and Server 2012 internal features.

The VC11 binaries loads VC11, VC10 and VC9 modules, and does not run on XP and 2003. Minimum system required: Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8 / 8.1, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012 / R2

After you have downloaded and before you attempt to install it, you should make sure that it is intact and has not been tampered with. Use the PGP Signature and/or the SHA Checksums to verify the integrity.

Thank you

Comment: This really doesn't help since he's using Mac OS X.

Answer (score -2):

/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf
default:
"ServerSignature On"
this setting enables the force HSTS feature for the server by default and ignores the vhost settings.
for example:
Your server is named server.com
if you created vhost: server.com
vhost setting is ignored

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.